# Perl: Have output update dynamically

Tags: perl

I have a variable `$i` that goes from 1 to 100. Is it possible to have the page display the # dynamically replacing the # that was there before?

Suppose I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $i = 0;

for my $i ('1' .. '10') {
    print "$i";
    sleep(1);
}
```

How do I make it so instead of print "12345...", it just replaces the # that was there before. So `1` becomes `2`, `2` becomes `3`, etc

Comment: This post is now atrocious. Each half asks a different question, and the second question consists entirely of a code snippet which doesn't run. I can't even delete my answer (which only answers half) because it's been accepted (even though you're not happy with it). If you have a new question to ask, ask a new question. (You could properly update this one, unaccept my answer, and have me delete my answer, but it's way simpler just to ask a new question.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For something simple like that, you can just move the cursor back using backspace or carriage return.

```
$| = 1;  # Autoflush.

for my $i (1..10) {
   print("\r", $i);
   sleep(1);
}

print("\n");
```

Comment: What is the `$|` symbol?

Comment: Turn on autoflush on the currently selected output handle

Comment: This works for me but i have a weird issue bc i have a progressbar on the same line and the progressbar overwrites the value in here

Comment: @Bijan, move to a new line before printing the number?  Or perhaps just don't print a backspace with the first number.

Comment: For some reason it messes up the progress bar and instead of the progress bar being on one line, it becomes all on separate ones

Comment: Basically, it's going to come down to `print("\r", $progress_bar, " ", $i);`

Comment: I am using Term::ProgressBar and the progress bar is not printed like that. I tried what you said and it did not work. I updated original post with the code

Answer (score 2):

"\r" returns the cursor to the beginning of the line. Instead, you probably just want to backspace the last printed number, and print the next one... Something like this:

```
$| = 1;    
my $i = 0;
while ($i < 10) {
    print $i;
    sleep 1; # REPLACE WITH WHATEVER PROCESS YOU NEED TO DO
    print "\b" x length $i++;
}
```

The last line of the `while` loop prints a backspace the same length of the number it just printed, and then increments it. This is because the postfix `++` increments after evaluation.